# Javamail Adress.personal information set to null when reading email from lotus notes using spring

Tags: spring, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, spring-integration

I use spring integration to read email from a lotus notes server. Every thing is working as expected. the incoming MailMessage from header does not have the 'personal ' information set. it is set to null. Trying to figure out if something needs to change in the lotus notes server configuration for the inbox being polled or if it is a spring issue. using javamail 1.4.7 and SI 3.x . Any Advise would be appreciated

Comment: I am trying to retreive the FIRST NAME and LAST NAME of the sender.

Comment: Spring Integration is just a wrapper around `JavaMail` - he builds the message; we just wrap it in a Spring Integration message. Setting the javmail property `mail.debug` to `true` might give you some help.

Comment: thanks . for some reason the first name /last name is not available in the headers. decided to get the infromation from ldap. i got a question on that.i will create a seperate post for it .